# Google Chrome DNS Cache refers to the old site

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser

I changed one of my domain DNS records recently, but when I open the URL in Firefox, it works and it is on the new server.

Also I ping the domain using CMD and it shows the new IP address too.

But in Google Chrome, it still refers to the old IP address. How can I clear and disable dns cache in Chrome?

I used `chrome://net-internals/#dns` and cleared cache, but it still refers to the old site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a link to Chrome on your Desktop
- Right click - then Properties
- In Shortcut Tab - append --disable-async-dns to Target
- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-async-dns
- Start Chrome from that link
- go to chrome://net-internals/#dns
- Async DNS should be disabled
- Clear Host resolver cache

Comment: Thanks I also managed to get a new IP come through in an existing tab that was refusing to update, by going to chrome://net-internals/#dns  first  to clear host cache and then chrome://net-internals/#sockets and close/flush